# Counting houses for each person in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: Person and House.
Each person has a name, email, and a phone number, while a house has a number of rooms and a city location.
I have to show every person name and a number of houses, where the number of houses is the number of how many houses a person has.

This is seems to be a one-has-many relationship. 
So here is my query for the Person Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Person ( person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
       name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
       email VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL,
       phone_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL);
```

and here is the query of the House Table:

```
CREATE TABLE House (
    house_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    person_id INT NOT NULL,
    number_of_rooms INT NOT NULL,
    city_location VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES Person(person_id) );
```

As to show how many houses each person has, I wrote this query:

```
SELECT name AS "Person name", count(house_id) AS "Number of houses" FROM Person JOIN House WHERE Person.person_id = House.person_id;
```

But that query only shows only the first name I've inserted (inserted more) and the sum of house_id for that name (for house_id #1 & #2 & #3 the result should be as 3, but it show 6) and that's it.

When I thought of it for the first time, it's really easy to build, I don't know why I'm wasting so much time on this. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by`.  And, you should use an `ON` clause when you use `JOIN`.  I would also recommend table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT p.name AS "Person name", count(h.house_id) AS "Number of houses"
FROM Person p JOIN
     House h
     ON p.person_id = h.person_id
GROU PBY p.name;
```

Comment: Exactly! it worked just fine! and when it worked I really was like "why did I miss this?" :-/ Thanks Gordon

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.name AS "Person name", count(h.house_id) AS "Number of houses" 
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN House h ON h.person_id = p.person_id
GROUP BY p.name
```

This is what you need.

What I changed were the following:

- Added aliases to tables (comes in handy)
- Used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (`LEFT JOIN` for short) instead of an `INNER JOIN` (`JOIN` for short) in order to get even the people that have no matching house (number of houses will be zero for them)
- Added the `ON` clause for `JOIN` (required for syntax)
- Added a `GROUP BY` clause. Required for using aggregate functions like `COUNT`

Comment: Thanks Alexander! But I really don't think I need to list persons with no houses. I may need this when listing all person in the table. Thanks